# Consume and produce to the same channel from Kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to process some tasks with some set of workers. By processing I mean

- getting data from a queue
- sending a request over the network
- getting the result and posting it to the same queue

I don't want to hang up waiting for a response. So my idea was to use Kotlin's coroutines (and built-in `Job`s) as workers and a `Channel` for queuing up tasks

But I need my workers to consume from a channel and then producing next tasks to the **same** **channel**.

Let's say I have a task that looks like this:

```kotlin
data class Task(val id: Int) {
    suspend fun run(): List<Int> {
        println("starting $id")
        delay(id.toLong())  
        println("done  $id")

        if (id >= 5000) return listOf(6000, 7000, 8000)
        return listOf()
    }
}
```

And then 2 workers should process the queue:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    
    val channel = Channel<Task>()
    val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()

    // spawn 2 workers
    repeat(2) {
        val job = launch {
            for (task in channel) {
                val results = task.run()

                // --=== enqueue next task ===--
                for (result in results) {
                    launch(Unconfined) {
                        channel.send(Task(result))
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        jobs.add(job)
    }

    // send some seed data to the queue
    for (taskId in listOf(2000, 4000, 5000)) {
        channel.send(Task(taskId))
    }

    // close later
}
```

Let's say `val results = task.run()` actually returned me a list of next tasks - `[6000, 7000, 8000]`. When this happens they don't get processed

```kotlin
starting 2000
starting 4000
done  2000
starting 5000
done  4000
done  5000
Exception in thread "main" ClosedSendChannelException: Channel was closed
```

The channels get's closed and new tasks - `[6000, 7000, 8000]` - never get processed.

Can you please suggest how to organise processing properly so that the process continues?

Comment: Copied your exact example, works like a charm. I think your problem come from the code that closes the channel. Can you share it ? Does it properly **await** for a given condition / signal to close the channel ? Because the code will very quickly reach `// close later` line, as you jobs are **launch**ed asynchronously.

Comment: @amanin I didn't pay attention to when exactly the channel gets closed. But I double-checked that now and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @amanin's comment, I updated the code so it tracks the number of completed tasks with `AtomicInteger`. And (for the sake of simplicity) only closes the channel when all (6) tasks are processed

```
val done = AtomicInteger()

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    // ...
    
    for (task in channel) {
        // ...

        if (6 == done.incrementAndGet()) {
            channel.close()
        }
    
    // ...
    jobs.joinAll()
}
```